# npm - Error installin a plugin

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I´m new using npm, I want to install a plugin and I get the error below, I understand that the plugin requieres angular 2.1.2 and I'm using 2.0.1. 
How can I solve it without updating angular? I think the plugin doesn´t depends on angular version. 
Thanks!

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@2.0.1 wants @angular/common@2.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.1 wants @angular/common@2.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.1 wants @angular/common@2.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.1 wants @angular/common@2.0.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-notifications@0.4.46 wants @angular/common@^2.1.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-npm-package-does-not-satisfy-its-siblings-peerdependencies-requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this issue and it's because of your npm old version. try to update it as

`npm install npm -g`

and this error should go away!